# Total sum of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `4x9` matrix, and I need to calculate the sum of all numbers in every other column of c starting with the first. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know we have to use the function `sum()` but that's about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to change the title. What you ask is not what the title says

Answer (score 3):

I used Octave rather than MATLAB, but this works for me:

```
A = randi(10,4,9)
B = A(:, 1:2:9)
C = sum(B)
```

Generate a 4x9 matrix with random numbers between 1 and 10, then create a sub-matrix with each row, and given columns `1:2:9` means starting from the first column and ending on the 9th, choose every second column, then sum up each column. Example output:

```
>> A = randi(10,4,9)
A =

    1    3    6    8    2    8    4    8   10
    3    6   10    4    6    4    6    2    8
    4    3    9    2    7   10    6    9    6
    8    5    3    9    3    8    4    6   10

>> B = A(:, 1:2:9)
B =

    1    6    2    4   10
    3   10    6    6    8
    4    9    7    6    6
    8    3    3    4   10

>> C = sum(B)
C =

   16   28   18   20   34
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also take the sum of matrix C using the sum() first and then select every other element from the result starting from the 1st element.

```
tmpC = sum(C);
result = tmpC(1:2:end)
```